# renaming a temporary table into a physical one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can I do something like this?

```
create table #tbl_tmp (col1 int)

insert into #tbl_tmp select 3

exec sp_rename '#tbl_tmp','tbl_new'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

If you are running this from a database other than `tempdb` you get

> No item by the name of '#tbl_tmp' could be found in the current
>   database ....

Which is not surprising as all the data pages etc. are in the `tempdb` data files so you wouldn't be able to rename this to suddenly become a permanent table in an other database.

If you are running this from `tempdb` you get

> An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure
>   'sys.sp_rename'.

If you do `EXEC sp_helptext sp_rename` and look at the definition the relevant bit of code disallowing this is

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 --------------------  PHASE 32:  Temporay Table Isssue -------------------  
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 -- Disallow renaming object to or from a temp name (starts with #)  
 if (@objtype = 'object' AND  
  (substring(@newname,1,1) = N'#' OR  
  substring(object_name(@objid),1,1) = N'#'))  
 begin  
  COMMIT TRANSACTION  
  raiserror(15600,-1,-1, 'sys.sp_rename')  
  return 1  
 end
```

Why wouldn't you just create a permanent table in the first place then do the rename?

Comment: yes, I realized that in order to be able to call sp_rename the table must have an object_id associated whereas the temp tables don't have one.

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei - They do. Try `use tempdb; select object_id('#tbl_tmp')` or from another database context `select object_id('tempdb..#tbl_tmp')`

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know this is not possible outside of `tempdb`.

Instead of renaming the table, you can create a new one from the temporary one.

Untested:

```
SELECT * 
INTO tbl_new
FROM #tbl_tmp
```

Comment: yeah I know this one but I was trying to use sp_rename.

Comment: @MartinSmith - But it _does_ give a different option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. You can implement something like it but in a workaround way.
Try the following approach, a lil bit old school but bypasses the restriction. I tested it myself as well

```
/* Create an empty temporary staging table **/
use aw_08r2
go
-- create temporary table
select * into #temp from person.address 

-- select data from temporary staging table
select * from #temp

-- convert the temporary table and save as physical table in tempdb
select * into tempdb.dbo.test from #temp

-- save a copy of the physical table from tempdb in aw_08r2
select * into person.test from tempdb.dbo.test

-- select data from physical table
select * from #temp
select * from tempdb.dbo.test
select * from person.test

-- drop temporary table and physical table from tempdb
drop table #temp
drop table tempdb.dbo.test
go
```