# Error renaming a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to rename a temporary table?

```
create table #t (id integer);
execute tempdb.sys.sp_rename '#t', '#s';

An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sys.sp_rename'
```

The proposed solution by @Michel, inserting into another temp table and dropping the original, works but I guess how expensive it is.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552550/renaming-a-temporary-table-into-a-physical-one

Comment: @Turque That question is about renaming a temp to a permanent table. As they reside in different databases it is obviously more complex, if not impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tempdb doesn't have the sp_rename procedure. What you could do is to create a new temptable with the contents of your old one

Something like this

```
select * into #NewName from #OldName
drop table #OldName
```

Comment: `tempdb` does have the `sp_rename` procedure. This is accessible in all databases. It is specifically coded to raise an error for `#temp` objects though.

Comment: selecting into a new table seems purpose-defeating.  if you've already got your data in a table and you just need to use that table data or refer to it by another name... this involves reinserting/reindexing data. insane.  it's like there's no way to refer to a table by reference in SQL. and then, the one shot we have at it is renaming a temp table.. and they stick special logic to throw and error for them? wth.

Comment: Indirect reference is possible via synonym.  There is no such thing as a temporary synonym making clashes and cleanup a problem.  So while there isn't a decent solution there is this other option.